# Motivo de cierre: La pregunta no demuestra ninguna investigación ni esfuerzo

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

¿ Sería posible añadir un nuevo motivo de cierre a los ya existentes ?

Casos es los que **considero** que los motivos de cierre existentes no son aplicables con la suficiente exactitud:

- Preguntas de tareas escolares sin mostrar ningún trabajo previo.

  Aquí suelo marcar `Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir ...`

- Preguntas sobre sintaxis de lenguajes o conceptos **muy básicas** de programación, como por ejemplo

  [Pregunta de C++ y unsigned](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/396050/19610)

  Aquí, sencillamente, **no supe que opción de cierre aplicar**.

Creo que a ambos grupos de preguntas se les puede aplicar algo como

> La pregunta no demuestra ningún trabajo de investigación ni esfuerzo previo

La intención es indicar al usuario que ha de demostrar su participación en el proceso de resolución de un problema, no limitándose a esperar a que se lo proporcionen todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿ Que opináis ?
¿ Sería conveniente un motivo de cierre con esa descripción ?
¿ Es posible añadir un nuevo motivo de cierre ?

Comment: creo, que no podiamos agregar ninguno mas... creo.. pikoh se encargo de eso la ultima vez...

Comment: Agregale a la descripción "Aqui no se hacen tareas escolares", o algo del estilo.

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo pensé :-) ... pero lo descarté para no limitar demasiado el *alcance* del motivo de cierre. Creo que, con lo que propongo, es aplicable a mas casos: tanto tareas escolares como preguntas que, llevadas a Google, dan 100.000.000 de resultados, o cosas tan básicas que son de 1º de parvulario de programación, y apenas pueden calificarse como preguntas *reales*.

Comment: incluiria en este motivo código que no compila (errores de sintaxis, variables no definidas,  etc), salvo que sea el tema de la pregunta misma.

Comment: @CandidMoe para errores de sintaxis me parece ya existe motivo de cierre relacionado a: **Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.**

Comment: @BetaM. No lo había interpretado así. Tal vez podría mantener el motivo explicitando que incluye código que no compila.

Comment: Aqui hay una pregunta que calza exactamente en esta categoria: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/396338/tengo-este-error-al-implementar-una-api-indentationerror-unindent-does-not-mat

Comment: A mí me parece que más que más motivos para este tipo de preguntas, habría que tener menos. Ya tenemos _Necesita más detalles_, _Necesita ser más específica_ y _necesita comportamiento esperado blabla_.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Entonces, preguntas que devuelven 100.000.000 de resultados en cualquier buscador, o sobre los ante-primeros pasos en un lenguaje (la que expongo pregunta que significa `unsigned`, y yo entiendo que viene de un lenguaje sin tipar en el que solo se indica el nombre de las variables) ... ¿ Que se hace con ellas ? ¿ Que motivo indico en el voto de cierre ?

Comment: @Trauma que tenga resultados en cualquier buscador no creo que sea motivo de cierre. Al fin y al cabo, querríamos que este sitio fuera el de referencia ante cualquier duda y que el primer resultado en un buscador fuera el de este sitio, por lo que veo dos opciones: 1) Si ya está contestado anteriormente, marcarla como duplicada. 2) Si no lo está, tunearla para que sea fácil de encontrar y entender y ponerle una buena respuesta para que sea una pregunta canónica.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Sin embargo, cuando paso el ratón sobre el botón de votar +, aparece un *tooltip* que dice `Estra pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara`. Personalmente, opino que *tropecientos* resultados en la primera búsqueda no demuestran mucho trabajo de investigación. Pero bueno, visto el número de votos de esta propuesta ... se ve que soy una *rara avis* :-/

Comment: ¡Claro, toda la razón! Y votar positivamente no tendría sentido. Pero una cosa es el voto y otra si la pregunta debe ser cerrada.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Raro es la que se merece -1 y no presenta un motivo de cierre. Las hay, por temas *interesantes* o ser *atrayantes* de visitas, pero la mayoria ...

Comment: he leido todo, y despues recorde los post por "null pointer" y me heche a reir XD

Comment: yo meteria todo en algo como: **tu pregunta no cumple con los requisitos minimos del sitio (link a help); verifica que dicen los comentarios de otros usuarios para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida**

Answer (score 1):

Apoyo la propuesta.

Hay dos partes en el tema:

- El trabajo que el usuario hizo por resolver su problema.
- La formulación de la pregunta.

Las alternativas "Faltan detalles o aclaraciones" y "Necesita ser más específica" se refieren a aspectos formales de la pregunta, la que puede ser salvada completando la información que falta o eliminando las partes superfluas.

"Faltan detalles" es cuando faltan los datos de entrada, o el resultado esperado, o el mensaje de error, cosas que sólo pasan cuando el usuario ya ha intentando algo.

"Necesita ser más específica" es cuando el usuario pregunta dos o tres cosas a la vez, cada una de ellas tal vez meritorias y dignas de ser formuladas en forma separada.

"Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración ..." sólo aplica cuando el usuario tiene un código legalmente válido que no produce el resultado esperado (o se cae durante la ejecución).

La alternativa propuesta "No demuestra ningún esfuerzo ..." es otra cosa: dice que el usuario no ha hecho nada por resolver su problema. Es una pregunta insalvable. Aquí no "faltan detalles", aquí falta todo. Es un pregunta que no puede "ser más específica", pues contiene tan poca información que sacarle algo es reducirla a nada. Y tampoco hay "depuración" posible cuando no hay código que ejecutar.

Comment: Veo que has entendido perfectamente mi razonamiento, y lo explicas mejor que yo. Lástima que la propuesta no vaya a prosperar, vista la poca cantidad de positivos que tiene :-(

Comment: @Trauma he visto post con mas votos positivos que nisiquiera fueron considerados ... pero bueno ... a ver que tanto esfuerso le meten los responsables del sistema.